# R – reading in and then extracting the same cell from a list of binary img files

Tags: r

I’m trying to extract the values of the same [i,j] cell from ~14000 img files. I’ve set up a working function that did this for smaller batches where it was reasonable to put the files in my directory, but now that I’m ready to look at the larger dataset I’m stuck. The img files are organized by year, with 365 separate files for each of 38 winters. Each winter has its own folder (WS1978_1979data, WS1979_1980data, etc.), and each day has its own file containing snow depth data for a large satellite grid in the Arctic (ssmi_n_snowdepth_5day_1978307.img, ssmi_n_snowdepth_5day_1978308.img, etc.) starting October 1 and going through September 30 of the following year. My ultimate hope (at least for this stage) is to create a vector of 365 snow depths for the cell of interest and to do this for each year in the dataset.

I can specify the appropriate file path to generate a list of the files I want for a given year, but then when I use my function to extract the particular cell I want, it looks for the file in the directory, which is wrong. Can you help me out? I feel like I must be missing something simple but I haven’t been able to find what I need.

Example of making a list of all the files for the winter of 1979-1980:

```
w1979s1980 <-  as.vector(list.files(path="SnowDepth/WS1979_1980data", pattern=".img"))`
```

Function to extract the snow depth from a given cell for all the files in that list:

```
cell.depthKotz <- function(depthfile){
  depth.val <- c()
  for(i in 1:length(depthfile)) {
  depth.mat <- matrix(readBin(depthfile[i], what="integer", n=136192, size=2, endian="little"), 
                      nrow=448, ncol=304, byrow=TRUE)
  depth.val[i] <- depth.mat[187,65]
  depth.val[depth.val == 110] <- NA
  depth.val[depth.val == 120] <- NA
  depth.val[depth.val == 130] <- NA
  depth.val[depth.val == 140] <- NA
  depth.val[depth.val == 150] <- NA
  depth.val[depth.val == 160] <- NA
  }  
  return(depth.val)
}
```

And then probably save this as a vector when I run the function for a given year:

```
Sdepths1978.1979 <- as.vector(cell.depthKotz(w1979s1980))
```

I should add that I’m very new to all this as far as even knowing how to phrase what I’m asking for, so let me know if I need to edit the title/question or add more detail. I’m not concerned about runtime if you see that sort of inefficiency in the functions above, but if there are obvious changes that would mean less repetitive/manual effort from me and more automated effort from R feel free to say so. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `recursive` flag in the `list.files` function.

```
files <- list.files(path = "src", pattern = "\\.jpg$", recursive = TRUE)
```

If you make the path point to the parent directory. And add the `recursive = T` flag you should be good.

Optionally you can change the pattern to end with `$` stating the files must end with this pattern. In a rare case where there is another file in the directory named `someinfo.img.txt` this would be ignored.